# Handling dates and times in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, date, time, format

So im working with morris charts, im showing all the data we have for today.

I have an array like below:

```js
[0] => Array (
    [id] => 1
    [uid] => 6161
    [botted] => 0
    [crondate] => 2016-06-08 00:20:32
    )
[1] Array ( 
    [id] => 2
    [uid] => 4141
    [botted] => 140
    [crondate] => 2016-06-08 00:40:00
    )
[2] Array ( 
    [id] => 3
    [uid] => 53
    [botted] => 40
    [crondate] => 2016-06-08 01:12:20
    )
[3] Array ( 
    [id] => 4
    [uid] => 5
    [botted] => 140
    [crondate] => 2016-06-08 01:18:00
    )
[4] Array ( 
    [id] => 5
    [uid] => 353
    [botted] => 88
    [crondate] => 2016-06-08 01:50:00
    )
```

(I hand writ the array, its a result of a SELETE * FROM items QUERY)

I need all of the rows formatted by date then added to seperate arrays depending on the date.

I need them formated by the hour, example:

All of the rows with the date inside of 1pm today, added to an array FOR THAT HOUR.

All of the rows with the date inside of 2pm today, added to an array FOR THAT HOUR.

etc, etc...

I need this done for every hour of the day(up to the current hour) so that i can add up all of the ['botted'] columns for that hour, add that to an array and display it in a MORRIS CHART

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe I don't quite get the question, please be more specific. I don't know *what you need for morris chart* --- `$arr = []; foreach($hours as $hour) $arr[] = $hour['crondate'];`

Comment: @m02ph3u5 Thanks for the reply. I have editted the question, let me know if that makes any more sense now.

Comment: My first instinct would be a SQL `GROUPBY`.  "crondate" is of type datetime, correct?

Comment: @MarcBarbeau its TIMESTAMP with default to current timestamp, should i change it to datetime? Also, does GROUPBY group all of the rows by the hour? if so, how would i handle the result of that so that i can access the "botted" column of each row within that group(s)?

Comment: Iterate through the array, parse the date, extract the hour, add the sub-array to your *morris-chart-array*. - So the real question is *"How to parse dates in PHP*, is it not?

Comment: I find it helpful to include an end result in the question. For this I am picturing  `[2016-06-08 00:00:00] = (0+140)` and `[2016-06-08 01:00:00] = (40+80+88)`